# Mongo ruby setFeatureCompatibilityVersion

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Using mongo (3.4) in a rails app (5.2) with mongo ruby driver.
I need to use collation on the collection to allow case-insensitive text search, and for that I received a warning that I need to add setFeatureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4.

```
client  = Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'], :database => 'leads')
db = client.database
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
collection_name = "#{user.id.to_s}"
@collection = client[collection_name.to_sym, { "collation" => { "locale" => "en_US" } }]
...
```

But getting  `NoMethodError (undefined method`adminCommand' for #)`

I'm not using mongoid for this case, so using a model for this using mongoid is not possible.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE::**

What did just work was that I accessed mongo shell with mongo and entered

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Is this command only supposed to be applied to the db directly in shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in Ruby driver to run arbitrary commands is `Database#command`:

https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Database.html#command-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Documentation was recently moved to https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/

What you are trying to do, can be achieved from the ruby driver with the `command` method:

```
db.command({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: '3.4' })
```